# Wordpress and Mybb

Tags: php, wordpress, mybb

Yes I know that there is a plug in to bridge the two, but I want to keep them separate. Basically I want the nav menu in wordpress to point to a sub domain or a folder with the mybb forums. Everyone keeps telling me to use the plug in. Also if you add folders to wordpress, will it not just give you errors that those pages do not exist? So is a subdomain the best choice?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely fine to keep the two separate without using the bridge.  If you want a link to MyBB from a Wordpress menu, you can add it in the Admin Panel -> Appearance -> Menus, add a Custom Link to your forum URL.

By default, the .htaccess file in Wordpress will not rewrite URLs any folders/files that exist on the server.  So it *is* possible to have MyBB as a subfolder in your Wordpress installation.  However, it may be cleaner and easier to maintain if you have it on a separate subdomain.